# Vector or list in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there anything like vector or list in oracle sql for storing the user defined objects ?

Comment: In my opinion, the Oracle documentation is clear and easy to understand and certainly contains the answer to your question, as [Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot) has shown. I think you should consider reading it. At least the _SQL Language Reference_ and perhaps also the _PL/SQL Language Reference_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, these are [user defined types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375).

In PL/SQL, these are [collections and records](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005).

Presuming, of course, that *vectors or lists* represent something of those.